# Ошибка синтаксиса в написании функции SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне нужно написать функцию в postgreSQL, которая изменяет/добавляет новую строку в таблицу. функция должна добавлять новую строку, если ее параметр in_id = 0, и заменять строку, если in_id равен id строки. Просмотрел примеры upsert, прочел доку по postgreSQL. Вроде бы все сделано согласно синтаксису указанному в документации, но выдается ошибка

> ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "ON") 
>   LINE 27:  ON CONFLICT( id ) 
>   Код функции

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_test(
    in_id integer,
    in_author text,
    in_summary text,
    in_story text,
    in_topic text,
    in_date date
)

RETURNS SETOF public.test
AS
$$
    INSERT INTO public.test(
        author,
        summary,
        story,
        topic,
        date
    ) 
    VALUES(
        in_author,
        in_summary,
        in_story,
        in_topic,
        in_date
    ) RETURNING id

    ON CONFLICT( id ) 

    WHERE id = in_id

    DO UPDATE SET
        author = in_author,
        summary = in_summary,
        story = in_story,
        topic = in_topic,
        date = in_date; 
$$

LANGUAGE SQL
VOLATILE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

В общем вопрос в том чтобы избавиться от ошибки в синтаксисе или последующих ошибок, если они есть.

Comment: Ну так глянь, значить, справку-то... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html ... и сразу увидишь, что RETURNING бывает после ON CONFLICT, а не перед им.

Comment: @Akina, я изменил порядок, поставил RETURNING в конец функции, что позволило мне получить что надо